# Robust processing of autogenerated LaTeX files that contain many errors

Tags: errors, compiling, automation, knitr

I use `knitr` to generate pretty reports, with `pdflatex` as backend. Everything works fine if the R code runs without error. However, if the R code fails, the autogenerated file is sometimes invalid in such a way that LaTeX won't even generate a PDF out of it -- too many errors, resulting in the following output:

```
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Example: `texput.tex`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  \input{bad}
\end{document}
```

Example: `bad.tex`

```
\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e
\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e
\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e
\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e
```

(The code, and a `Makefile`, can be downloaded or cloned [here](https://github.com/krlmlr/lm-template/tree/robust-input).)

In such cases, the error in the R script is difficult to find, because no output is available.

Is there a foolproof equivalent of `\input` that will "just work" in such cases? It's fine even if the resulting document ends abruptly at the place of the fatal error, as long as a valid PDF is generated. Or perhaps just setting the error threshold to an insanely large value and/or resetting the number of encountered errors after each `\input` will help?

Comment: add `\batchmode` at the top of your file (or the equivalent commandline argument to your call to pdflatex) Then TeX will try its hardest to not stop and get to the end somehow.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm seeing `(That makes 100 errors; please try again.) -- !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!` in batch mode...

Comment: well I only say that TeX would try it's hardest I didn't promise it would succeed, that's the best I can think of if I understand the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for looking into it. I have added more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot be sure that a completely arbitrary LaTeX document will compile: there are lots of cases that lead for example to an infinite loop. In the case of the `100 errors` message this is built in to TeX, not LaTeX, and so it can't simply be 'turned off' by LaTeX. In DVI mode you may get some readable output from such cases, as the DVI format doesn't require a valid 'end of file' section, but PDFs do so pdfTeX has to get to the end of a job to give you something usable.

Comment: This is a pity, but I guess we'll have to live with it.